# Duplicate search box, not getting any search result

Tags: php, search, post, opencart, opencart2.x

I have two search boxes, one for desktop and one for mobile version. I created two versions because of their different positions on website.
Both has the same code, but the mobile version is not getting any search results in url.

Desktop working version url on submit button :

```
 index.php?route=product/search&search=test
```

Mobile version url (not sending data in url) :

```
index.php?route=product/search
```

Both of them has this input :

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>"  value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
```

I don't understand why the mobile version is not sending data.

Comment: You should be able to use remote debugging on a mobile device using Chrome or similar method to see what's going on. reference (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

Comment: make sure you put the search box inside header tag

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 reasons-

1st - you didn't added your search input to inside header tag (suggested by ramesh)
2nd - if 1st is done, then you have to also change in your common.js file which is responsible for searching, where code is added

```
$('#search input[name=\'search\']').on('keydown', function(e) {
```

add this code to add class to active input type,

```
$(this).addClass('active-header-input');
```

then you have to change this line

```
 var value = $('header input[name=\'search\']').val();
```

because it is just taking 1st input value and never take 2nd one so change it to this

```
 var value = $('.active-header-input').val() ? $('.active-header-input').val() : $('header input[name=\'search\']').val();
```

now your both input will work.